# libnfc emulate tag type4(14443b)

Tags: c, emulation, nfc, rfid, lib-nfc

I have 2 questions about emulate and libnfc.

1. I saw on [PN53x](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=PN53x) that  i can't emulate iso14443b with pn53x , why is that?  how can i emulate it on another way ?
2. when i tried to emulate tag type 4 with the exmample that on site  with 2 reader of acr122u.

when i put those 2 reader Close (1 for emulate 1 for read) i get on this [line](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/utils/nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.c#L141)  `ba 00` every second.

why is that? is that the reader looking for tag?

I don't find the documentation of this command, what should i answer to this so i can start the conversation between the emulate and the reader?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't emulate 14443B with PN532. It is impossible on the firmware level. But you can use board, based on TI RF430CL330 or RF430CL331 for your application. I am not sure if such boards are sold somewhere, but there is no difficulty to develop custom one, there is RF430CL330 Arduino library on github.
2. Not familiar with libnfc, but that 0xba seems to be sent from application level. If both of your cards runs libnfc-based software you could do search over the libnfc sources to see where it comes from.